# Java 8 Optional Code review

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I just want to check if I am doing this right. Is this the correct way of using optional or can there something be improved?

```
String longitudeResult = "Address_Longitude is empty or null;";
String latitudeResult = "Address_Latitude is empty or null;";
if (Optional.ofNullable(location).isPresent()) {
    Optional<Double> longitude = Optional.ofNullable(location.getLongitude());
    Optional<Double> latitude = Optional.ofNullable(location.getLatitude());
    if (longitude.isPresent()) {
        longitudeResult = longitude.get().toString();
    }
    if (latitude.isPresent()) {
        latitudeResult = latitude.get().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: are you using optional just for the sake of it ?

Comment: What else I can do with it? I thought it's just a replacement for null check.

Comment: If you're using `isPresent()` and `get()`, that's a pretty good hint that you're probably doing something wrong. Not to mention that the main advantage of `Optional` is when you return it from a method: if you create it and unpack it within three lines of each other, you might as well not bother.

Comment: @TimSchwalbe `Optional` is **not** a direct replacement for a null check, and calling `isPresent()` usually means you're using `Optional` without really understanding why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no point in `Optional` if you don't use its combinators:

```
Optional<Location> locationOptional = Optional.ofNullable(location);
String longitudeResult = locationOptional
        .map(Location::getLongitude)
        .map(Object::toString)
        .orElse("Address_Longitude is empty or null;");
String latitudeResult = locationOptional
        .map(Location::getLatitude)
        .map(Object::toString)
        .orElse("Address_Latitude is empty or null;");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems not to be wrong, but you could chain your calls using [ifPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-). Something like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(location).ifPresent(location -> {
  Optional.ofNullable(location.getLatitude()).ifPresent(
    latitude -> latitudeResult = latitude.get().toString());       
  Optional.ofNullable(location.getLongitude().ifPresent(
    longitude -> longitudeResult = longitude.get().toString());   
});
```

Shorter code is almost always better to me...

PS.: This code was not ckecked by a compiler.

Comment: Actually, despite my suggestion may works, the accepted one is pretty much better.